# Magento Form Tutorial

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I am a Beginner so i want to create simple form module Can any one suggest me some **magento form tutorial** for both **Frontend** and **Backend** I check many tutorial it create confusion so can you please refer simple form tutorial

Answer (score 1):

i suggest following tutorial for creating the form in admin panel

http://codegento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/

for frontend

http://blog.magestore.com/lesson-14-form-on-magento-frontend-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Check below site

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/

http://inchoo.net/category/magento/

These are best sites for Beginner

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this one here is the best resource for all besides looking around here.

https://github.com/aleron75/mageres